# Run a counter on Woocommerce Categories

Tags: php, wordpress, counter, woocommerce

I have developed a custom template in my theme where I want to call on certain Woocommerce Categories to display in different parts of the page.  I know I can use this shortcode:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[product_categories columns="6" number="6"]'); ?>
```

to display categories, however the problem I am running into is that I need to call on that shortcode several times in the template and each time it is called it shows the same 6 categories.  I would like to control the "number" a little more freely so I guess a counter of sorts would do the trick and then assign it to a variable??  Still kinda new to this but that seemed like the most logical approach based on what I know how to do unless someone can reccomend something differently for me.

The end results is that top of the page will have categories 1-6 and towards middle of the page would have maybe 6-9  and at the bottom of the page would have 9-15 or whatever.  I dont even know if the shortcode is the best way to do this but I have been stuck on it for hours :/

Would I need to run something similar to:

```
<?php $categories = get_terms( 
                      'product_cat', 
                      array(
                          'hide_empty' => 0,
                          'number'     => 6,   // This gives you 6 terms
                          'offset'     => 6    // This offsets the query, 0 means 1-6, 6 means 7-12...etc
                      )
                  );

                foreach ($categories as $cat) {

                    //print_r($cat);

                    $category_id = $cat->term_id;
                        $thumbnail_id   = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
                        $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
                        echo '<div class="two columns end"><a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'"><img height="150" width="150" src="'.$image.'" alt="'. $cat->name .'"/>'. $cat->name .'</a></div>';
                    }
                 ?>
```

Guess I just need a little help getting this going, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

You can do something like this:

```
$categories = get_terms( 
    'product_cat', 
    array(
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'number'     => 6,   // This gives you 6 terms
        'offset'     => 0    // This offsets the query, 0 means 1-6, 6 means 7-12...etc
    )
);
```

You would still need to style the output.

Do a `print_r($categories);` to see the format of the output.

Comment: awesome!!!  I am still having trouble setting this up, especially to show and link the thumbnails.. Sorry I am a noob here

Comment: I updated the code block above so you can see what I am doing, Im surre it is not 100% correct but how would I display the thumbs and have them link to the appropriate pages?  Would I be using post_thumbnail?

Comment: Hey sorry, OK so I got the images coming through but they are not actually the thumbnails, just scaled down versions of the larger images..  When I look at source I see the path is like (.../images/my-image.jpg) but instead I need the updated code above to pull the actualy thumb sizes so it should read something like {.../images/my-image-150x150.jpg) or whatever it is but these are not technically the thumbs, anyway to get those?

Comment: got it, had to change to this: 'wp_get_attachment_thumb_url'

Thanks guys!